# How to pass different function as props to the same component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

"I am trying to add comment functionality in my react application and I want to call different functions depending on my user type"

"I have successfully applied the logic and also I am able to post comments and save it."

Here's my Code for CommentForm.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addComment } from '../../actions/userdata';

const CommentForm = ({ userdataId, addComment }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {/* <div className='bg-primary p'>
        <h3>Leave a Comment</h3>
      </div> */}
      <form
        className='form my-1'
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addComment(userdataId, { text });
          setText('');
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          name='text'
          cols='3'
          rows='3'
          placeholder='Any Other Comments..'
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-dark my-1' value='Submit' />
        <small> {'<==='} Press this button to save Comments</small>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

CommentForm.propTypes = {
  addComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { addComment }
)(CommentForm);
```

and I am using this in some other file as

```
<CommentForm userdataId={userdata._id}/>
```

The problem is that I have around 9 functions like addComment say addcommenti, addcommentii, addcommentiii,.... and so on in ../actions/userdata.

and Hence I'll have to create 9 files.
I already tried

```
<CommentForm userdataId={userdata._id} addComment={addCommenti}/>
```

but it's not working i.e it's making call to addComment and not to addCommenti .
Any ideas on how to proceed ?

Here's my addComment Function

```
//Add Comment
export const addComment = (userdataId, formData) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `/api/userdata/comment/${userdataId}`,
      formData,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_COMMENT,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Comment Added', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: USERDATA_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What are the 9 different comment functions doing differently from one another?

Comment: "but it's not working" is not a valid error report, you're doing it right - at least conceptually. Please clarify what is happening; why it's not working.

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson my 9 different functions are making calls to diiferent api

Comment: @FredrikSchön it's not working here means the function which is being called is addComment and not addCommenti

Comment: Just pass all 9 functions as props from redux if you need them all

Comment: If you pass addComment in, it is just replaced by the redux action. If you want to be able to override the redux action you need to use the functional version of mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson Thanks for helping but I am not really familiar with mapDispatchToProps and hence having problem carrying it out. I am not actually able to understand how to implement your idea.

Are you asking me to do something like this and pass it to connect?

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addCommentaci: (text, userdataId) => {
      dispatch(addCommentaci(userdataId, { text }));
    },
    addCommentacii: (text, userdataId) => {
      dispatch(addCommentacii(userdataId, { text }));
    }
  };
};

Comment: @DharamDhurandhar you must call this.props.addComment, which you map to `addCommenti` where you use the component like you mentioned: `<CommentForm userdataId={userdata._id} addComment={addCommenti}/>`. I assume you're calling `addComment` in the reducer, which doesn't have `addCommenti`

Answer (score 0):

You have an imported function and a prop with the same name, that seems to cause the problem here: You think that you access the prop, but actually your component calls the imported function.

Try to remove the object destructuring in your CommentForm Component function and call this code instead:

```
// ...
const CommentForm = (props) => { /* <<-- HERE */
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        className='form my-1'
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          props.addComment(props.userdataId, { text }); /* <<-- HERE */
          setText('');
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          name='text'
          cols='3'
          rows='3'
          placeholder='Any Other Comments..'
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-dark my-1' value='Submit' />
        <small> {'<==='} Press this button to save Comments</small>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
// ...
```

This will explicitly use the function that you pass into the props and can not call the imported function by accident.

Though, you could also rename the prop to something like `onAddComment` so your prop and imported function always use different names (which makes the easier to understand, in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

So two things:

If you need to use 9 functions in your component, even if you only need one per user type, I would pass all 9 functions down and handle the logic for which to use there.

In this case you just want to add the remaining functions as you have already.

If you do want to override an action which is being injected using redux so that you can decide which function to pass in the parent component you can do it using the functional version of mapDispatchToProp; it has a second argument ownProps which you can use:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  addComment: (text, userdataid) => dispatch(addComment(userdataid, { text }),
  ...ownProps,
});
```

because I have spread ownProps *after* declaring addComment, you can pass addComment from the parent and it will replace the one we declared above.